# Angular - How to Validate each step in Angular Material stepper

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am implementing Material Stepper. And it has two (2) steps:

Component:

```js
export class SignupCompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = true;
  isLoading = false;
  companySetupForm!: FormGroup;
  companyForm!: FormGroup;
  idForm!: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]]
    });
    this.idForm = this.fb.group({
      registrationNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    });
  }

  get fc() {
    return this.companyForm.controls;
  };
  get fi() {
    return this.idForm.controls;
  };

  onSubmit() {}
}
```

HTML:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="companyForm">
    <form [formGroup]="companyForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel matStepperIcon="phone">Company Info</ng-template>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Company Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>}
          <input type="text" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.touched && fc.companyName.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('minlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be less than 3 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="idForm">
    <form [formGroup]="idForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Company ID</ng-template>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="registration_number">Registration Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="registrationNumber" placeholder="Registration Number" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.touched && fi.registrationNumber.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="success" [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
                <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                  Submit
              </button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

When each formControl is touched, the Material Stepper works fine. It displays the error immediately.
But when **Next Button** is clicked no data is filled in Step1 (companyForm), though it didn't move to the next step or form, but no error is displayed.

I want it to validate each step and display as it is done when each form control is touched.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two things I do is set field validation to `onBlur` like;

```
this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: ['',
                   [Validators.required,
                    Validators.minLength(3),
                    Validators.maxLength(100)]]
    },
    { updateOn: "blur" });
```

...and personally I don't like to allow continuing until the required fields are valid so I set the stepper button to disabled until it is like;

```
<button mat-raised-button
        color="primary"
        matStepperNext
        [disabled]="companyForm.status != 'VALID'">
   Next
</button>
```

Or definitely see Mr. Manhattan's comment below to validate the form at the end, which you can accomplish the same thing by changing the `{ updateOn: "blur" }` above from `blur` to `submit`

Comment: honestly, i'd just rebind the button, if invalid => markAllAsTouched(), if valid => stepper.next(), this way the attention of the user is drawn to the errors...which also seems closer to the asker's usecase

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan yea that's a good way too, perhaps providing an example answer would help others.

Comment: you already answered, so i didn't want to steal your show :)

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan until we can redeem points for prizes or something they're not that important, helping folks is more rewarding than SO points imo :D

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan - Can you explain your method or brief example?

Answer (score 2):

Material doesn't seem to mark the form as touched, so i'd rebind the button:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="onFirstStepDone()">Next</button>
```

in the component, you'll need a reference to the stepper:

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatHorizontalStepper;

onFirstStepDone() {
   if(!this.companyForm .valid) {
       // this should make all invalid fields light up in red
       this.companyForm.markAllAsTouched();
       return;
   }
   this.stepper.next();
}
```